# Как работает функция sort с датой?

Tags: javascript

```
const convertedDates = ['2022-03-18', '2022-03-10', '2022-03-05', '2022-03-06']

  console.log(convertedDates.sort(function(a,b){
        console.log(a,b)
        return new Date(a).valueOf() - new Date(b).valueOf()
    
       }))
```

Особенно меня интересует как определятся a и b?
Если написать `console.log(a,b) внутри функции`
То Получится такое

```
2022-03-10 2022-03-18
2022-03-05 2022-03-10
2022-03-06 2022-03-05
2022-03-06 2022-03-10
2022-03-06 2022-03-05
```

Как оно работает?

Comment: a, b - элементы массива. Сортирует по кол-ву миллисекунд в порядке возрастания.

Comment: Но в вашем примере вы сравниваете строки, а потом по результату уже создаете дату.

Comment: Почему a и b именно в таком порядке берутся из массива? Это такой внутренний способ работы функции sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Любая дата в JavaScript - это количество миллисекунд, прошедших от 1 января 1970 года, а значит это значение integer.

Получается, что `new Date("2022/06/12")` будет меньше чем `new Date("2022/07/12")`, потому что до последней прошло больше миллисекунд от 1 января 1970 года.

Таким образом, сортировка массива с датами аналогична тому, как сортируются массивы с числами.

В данном примере колбек функция получает строку у виде `2022-03-10`, потом из этой строки делается объект даты с помощью конструктора `new Date()`. Дальше происходит сортировка, описанная выше.

Answer (score -1):

Думаю вопрос был про то, как функция sort выбирает какие элементы сравнивать. Но дело в том, что это детали реализации функции sort - какой там внутри алгоритм. Можно написать абсолютно разные сортировки, которые принимают функцию сравнения. Результат(т.е отсортированный массив) одинаковый, но алгоритмы и соответственно пары сравниваемых элементов разные. Возьмите две любые простые сортировки, ну например пузырек и выбором, очевидно элементы там сравниваются по разному.

Comment: Вопрос скорее был в том, как JS понимает, что строки 2022-03-10 и 2022-03-18 сравниваются таким образом, что 2022-03-18 является большим чем 2022-03-10

Comment: "Особенно меня интересует как определятся a и b?"
Автор написал вот это. Как сравниваются строки / даты, думаю он понимает.